# ajaxswing - The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined

Tags: java, ajax, swing, batch-file, java-home

I have some problem to set `java home` on setEnv.bat from `AjaxSwing`

My JDK path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
```

My AjaxSwing :

```
C:\AjaxSwing4.3.3
```

from [there](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/doc/setup.html#test_install) I just set `JAVA_HOME` and `AJAXSWING_HOME` on setEnv.bat
so, I have edited the setEnv.bat as follows

```
rem set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
rem set AJAXSWING_HOME=C:\AjaxSwing4.3.3
rem set JAVA_OPTS=
rem set KEEP_CURRENT_DIR=true
```

But The Command Prompt still Says

**The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rem` is short for "remark" - it comments out the rest of the line in a batch script, so this snippet actually does **nothing**. Remove the `rem`s on the lines with the relevant paths and you should be OK:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
set AJAXSWING_HOME=C:\AjaxSwing4.3.3
```